# Does QT Phonon support video playback at different speeds?

Tags: qt, phonon

Does QT Phonon support video playback at different speeds? Can I play back at half speed or double speed? If not, is it known to be coming in a future version or will I have to hack it in myself?

Or, are there any alternative cross platform video playback libraries I should check out instead?

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall that last time I looked into this, Phonon supported being able to play back at different speeds, however it was unable to change the speed of the audio.  So, it could still be useful to you, depending on your requirements.

Comment: Is this documented anywhere? I am playing video and audio simultaneously in an app and would like to add the ability to speedup by a factor of two to both the video and audio. Is this simply not possible with Phonon?

Comment: I don't recall it being documented, I think we just found out when we tried it.  That was about a year ago now (around 4.6) so try it out in a prototype app.